# Control-M run job N days after ordering it

Tags: scheduling, control-m

I would like to order a job today in Control-M but have it run 8 days later, how would one go about doing this? Tomorrow the job should be ordered again for tomorrow's date and ran 8 days from tomorrow, so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

If you want run a job after  8days if it is not schedule on that date then you can order out that job on 7thdays depending up on time . Or if the request is that it should run on permantely on calendar days then you can add schedule and move job to production so that it get automatically order out and run.